# AS3 Compiler error 1083: problem with else syntax

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs3, if-statement

I'm creating a simple click and scroll for a future menu for my personal site. I have a box, I called it thing_mc, and I have 3 positions for it. I have a next and prev. button that will control thing_mc position. I'm using TweenLite to animate thing_mc, if that makes a difference.

I get a 1083 error (...else is unexpected) and (...rightparen is unexpected).

Can anyone tell me why and how I can resolve this?

Thanks

```
    import gs.TweenLite;

next_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextListener);
prev_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, prevListener);

//prev_mc.visible = false;

function nextListener(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(thing_mc.x == 400);
    {
    TweenLite.to(thing_mc, .5, {x:50, y:50});
    }
    else if //// i get error 1083 here (...else is unexpected)
    {
    TweenLite.to(thing_mc, .5, {x:-100, y:50}); //// i get error 1083 here (...rightparen is unexpected)
    }
}

function prevListener(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(thing_mc.x == -100);
    {
    TweenLite.to(thing_mc, .5, {x:400, y:50});
    }
    else if //// i get error 1083 here (...else is unexpected)
    {
    TweenLite.to(thing_mc, .5, {x:500, y:50}); //// i get error 1083 here (...rightparen is unexpected)
    }
}   

next_mc.buttonMode = true;
prev_mc.buttonMode = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not AS expert, but the semicolon after `if(thing_mc.x == 400);` and `if(thing_mc.x == -100);` seems strange. Should rather read `if(thing_mc.x == 400)` and `if(thing_mc.x == -100)` I'd say.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply.
I removed those strange semicolons and combined with the help above, it worked!!

Comment: So please mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking the big checkmark next to the number on the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if //// i get error 1083 here (...else is unexpected)
```

You have a few options here. You can either use a second condition, if you want to use `else if` i.e.

```
else if (someCondition) { ...
```

or, use just `else`

```
else { ...
```

or use another `if`

```
if { ...
```

It all depends on what you want to achieve.

From what I can see, the second option (plain `else`) looks like what you want.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply.
I went with else{
that worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
function nextListener(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(thing_mc.x == 400);
    {
```

Don't use `;` after the if brackets
;-)

Answer (score 0):

Wats going on is the parser sees
   if ( cond ) ;

as
   if ( cond ) /*empty statement*/ ; //semicolon ends empty statement

(and the else if /*...*/ of course lacked the parenthesized conditional expr that an if requiress).

I've seen this semicolon related error a lot. 
It may be because semicolons are optional in some cases in as3.